# Google Home user defined voice commands

Tags: groovy, actions-on-google, google-home, google-voice, home-automation

I have a google home speaker, and I can issue commands like `what's the time` or `play some music`, but I'd like to be able to define my own responses to certain commands, like

`how many appointments do I have today`
or
`are there any cancellations`

I would like the above commands to a run a script where I can either run a web-service, or pull information from my SmartThings hub (that bit is optional) and respond with an appropriate response.

I've done a bit of research, and it seems that IFTTT, can do something similar, but I don't really want to be dependent on a 3rd party app, and if this can be done directly with Google.

I guess I'm looking for something similar to Groovy for SmartThings, where I can write Smart Apps.

Answer (score 0):

The API to develop your own commands is known as [Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/). Broadly speaking, Actions will send JSON to a webhook that you control, and you can have it do whatever you wish at that point.